# My shifter shifts only one gear up and down

Tags: shimano, derailleur, shifter

I just was on a ride and all of a sudden I could only shift one gear up and down (in this case it was the 10th and 11th respectively the 21th and 22th). If I try to move the shifter further up (so up to the 9th and further) it blocks I cannot do it same problem with down shifting.

At home I tightend the shifter cable at the rear derailleur and now I can shift the 6th and 7th gear but nothing else. If I try the shifter does not move as above.

Any idea what the problem might be. I have the Grx 810 Group and the bike is about 5 month old, so it is not a brand shifting system.

Any help is welcome so I can get back on my bike.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shimano shifter neither reaching top nor bottom gear](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/69499/shimano-shifter-neither-reaching-top-nor-bottom-gear)

Comment: There are many questions and good answers on this site about shifting problems. The basic technique is to disconnect the cable from the derailleur and see if the shifter or the derailleur is jammed, then go though a derailleur sep up procedure.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the exact same issue. Even without the cable attached the shifter can move exactly between two "clicks" (up and down). Same story to how it started, out on a ride and suddenly it stopped shifting correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually caused by a shifter cable which is starting to break and fray. Usually you suddenly can’t shift to the smaller sprockets (hardest gears) anymore because the frayed cable jams inside the shifter or cable housing. It gets worse and worse until suddenly the remaining cable strands break and there is no tension on the cable any more which makes the derailleur move to the smallest (hardest) sprocket.

Depending on how much you shift this can already happen after a few thousand kilometers.